# Modify the manifest version for clickonce application -

Tags: version, clickonce, manifest

I have a ClickOnce application. It worked fine, but after another deployment it was broken with following exception:

> Unable to install this application because an application with the
>   same identity is already installed. To install this application,
>   either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall
>   the preexisting application.

I have already found how to fix this problem on client machine (via running *rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache*).

But I whould like to go another way, I want to change "manifest version" myself, without bothering the users.

So, do you know **how to modify the manifest version for clickonce application**?

Comment: Project > Properties > Publish > Publish Version?
Project > Properties > Application > Assembly Information > Assembly Version & File Version?

Comment: Definitely not Project > Properties > Publish > Publish Version

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'change the version without bothering the users' means. With a ClickOnce application, if you have a new version, you need to update the version number and publish an update to the same folder as the original. The next time the user runs the application (assuming you have updates turned on), he'll automatically get the update.

Can you be more specific about what exactly you are trying to accomplish? The application wouldn't just stop working if it worked the first time, unless you did something else -- what did you do?